# Scala Spark Streaming unit test with spark-testing-base throws error

Tags: scala, unit-testing, apache-spark, dstream

I was trying to run a unit test on my spark streaming code with [spark-testing-base](https://github.com/holdenk/spark-testing-base). And I am having trouble running their [sample-codes](https://github.com/holdenk/spark-testing-base/blob/master/src/test/1.3/scala/com/holdenkarau/spark/testing/SampleStreamingTest.scala).

Here is the code snippet I copied

import com.holdenkarau.spark.testing.SharedSparkContext
import org.scalatest.FunSuite

```
class SampleTest extends FunSuite with SharedSparkContext {
  test("test initializing spark context") {
    val list = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
    val rdd = sc.parallelize(list)

    assert(rdd.count === list.length)
  }
}
```

And here is the stacktrace of errors.

```
18/10/19 02:08:01 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable

An exception or error caused a run to abort. 
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.withScope(SparkContext.scala:701)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.parallelize(SparkContext.scala:718)
    at com.myproject.SampleTest$$anonfun$1.apply(DStreamTransformSpec.scala:11)
    at com.myproject.analytic.SampleTest$$anonfun$1.apply(DStreamTransformSpec.scala:9)
    at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf$class.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:85)
    at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf$.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:104)
```

I am including my build.sbt not sure if this help.

```
version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.12"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "2.2.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.bahir" %% "spark-streaming-pubsub" % "2.2.0"
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % "2.6.7"
libraryDependencies += "com.google.cloud" % "google-cloud-datastore" % "1.40.0"
// For test
libraryDependencies += "org.scalactic" %% "scalactic" % "3.0.5"
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.5" % "test"
libraryDependencies += "com.holdenkarau" %% "spark-testing-base" % "2.2.0_0.10.0" % "test"

fork in Test := true
javaOptions ++= Seq("-Xms512M", "-Xmx2048M", "-XX:MaxPermSize=2048M", "-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled")

assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
  case x => MergeStrategy.first
}

assemblyShadeRules in assembly := Seq(
  ShadeRule.rename("com.google.common.**" -> "repackaged.com.google.common.@1").inAll,
  ShadeRule.rename("com.google.protobuf.**" -> "repackaged.com.google.protobuf.@1").inAll
)
```

And is there any other tools, that are recommended to do testing with DStream?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you might have forgotten? I don't see it in build.sbt

```
parallelExecution in Test := false
```